# Setting delegate for CustomUiView getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, delegates

I have created a custom UIView and have a protocol set for it. Now from the View Controller when I set the delegate to self I am getting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

---The View Controller Code------

```
class VerificationController: UIViewController, LoadingViewDelegate {
   @IBOutlet weak var instructionView: LoadingView!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()           
       instructionView.randomTextIndexes = [1]
       instructionView.delegate = self 
   }

   ...
}

// "instructionView" is the UIView outlet and "LoadingView" is the class
```

--This is the custom View Code ------

```
protocol LoadingViewDelegate {
    func generated(random code:String)
}

class LoadingView: UIView {  
    var delegate:LoadingViewDelegate?
    var randomTextIndexes:[Int] = []
}
```

I am getting `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` when I try to access the delegate as well as the `randomTextIndexes` from the `viewDidLoad()` method of the view controller. Could you please tell me what I am missing here.

Comment: How are you adding the outlet to your code?

Comment: Is there a LoadingView in your storyboard, and is hooked up to your VerificationController by an outlet?

Comment: By clicking and dragging the UIView in the story board to the controller.

Comment: Yes,loadingView is there and is hooked up to VerificationController,

Comment: Can you give us the full error message?

Comment: @SaswatRajPandey - something in your code that you haven't shown must be causing the problem... assuming you have added `func generated(random code: String) { //some code }` in your `VerificationController`, your code as-shown works fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My best guess is that you forgot to set the class of the custom view in the Interface Builder. Check the Identity Inspector for your object in the IB, it should look like this:

[image: How it should look]

If it isn't set, then that's the problem.

Comment: It is set to the class. That was the first thing I looked at.

Comment: I had this error and it turned out that the "Module" setting for the class in Interface Builder had to be set. In my case the class was from a framework that was copied into the project.